# Is it legally required for visitors to Jamaica to have certain vaccinations in order to enter the country?

Tags: health, jamaica

Is it legally required for visitors to Jamaica to have certain vaccinations in order to enter the country? (Say I'm from one of the more affluent parts of the world.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visitors to Jamaica must have a yellow fever vaccination (and accompanying proof) if they've arriving from a yellow fever prone country.  Other than that there are plenty of recommended vaccinations but none required.

[Reference](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/jamaica)

[Reference](http://www.iamat.org/country_profile.cfm?id=54#profile_immunization)